# Using didSet causes function to be run multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, viewcontroller

In order to obtain values from a previous viewController, I use a `didSet` on a structure.

```
class ReviewViewController:  UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var detailBuilding: Building? {
    didSet {
        configureView()
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
    CKContainer.default()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("this override ran")
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

}

func configureView() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "RatingAttributes")
    print("the buildingID is \(String(describing: detailBuilding?.buildingID))")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "buildingID == %@", String(describing: detailBuilding?.buildingID))
    print("configuration ran")
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        //assert(result.count < 2)
        //print("the result we got was \(result[0])")
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print("The data was \(data.value(forKey: "buildingID")) ")
        }
    } catch {

        print("Failed to retreive core data")
    }
}
```

}

However, using print statements in the `func configureView()`, I am able to tell that the function runs 3 times. However, if I remove the call to `configureView()` from `viewWillAppear()`, then the view will not appear; if I remove it from `didSet`, then the values of detailBuilding (e.g `detailBuilding.rating`) will be nil. Though the third time the function runs, the values of detailBuilding are always nil anyway, meaning I can't use them.

In the previous viewController I have:

```
@objc func addReviewAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("ran this correctly")
    //navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    let controller = ReviewViewController()
    controller.detailBuilding = detailBuilding
    controller.navigationItem.title = ""
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = ""
    backItem.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
    navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    navigationController?.pushViewController(ReviewViewController(), animated: true)

}
```

I have checked multiple times to make sure I am not accidentally calling configureView() from anywhere else.

My questions are: Why is `configureView()` running multiple times? Why is `detailBuilding` nil on the 3 rd out of 3 times. And should I be using a different method for acquiring detailBuilding, as I need the values it contains for my NSPredicate.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your `configureView` method and look at the call stack and the instance's memory address each time it's called, that should give you the clues you need.

Comment: @Gereon Thank you for the suggestion, I tried it and found that it runs the one in the didSet first. However, if I remove the call in the viewDidAppear, then the view won't load. But If I remove the call in the didSet, then t he detailBuilding values will all be nil,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you just presented there should be only <s>one</s> two  calls of `configureView()`

1. made from `didSet`, right after the `controller.detailBuilding = detailBuilding` is executed.
2. made from `viewDidLoad` after object initialization

That being said, you need to provide more code, especially:

`viewWillAppear()` from `ReviewViewController` and code that triggers displaying the `ReviewViewController`.

EDIT:

Thanks for more details :)

You have an issue in line:
`navigationController?.pushViewController(ReviewViewController(), animated: true)`

it should be
`navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)`

That's why you've got `nil`. You are displaying a brand now ViewController not related to the one that have `detailBuilding` injected.

And that's why you've got 3 calls of `configureView()` method:

1. viewDidLoad of `controller` of type `ReviewViewController`
2. from injection (didSet)
3. viewDidLoad of unnamed object of type `ReviewViewController`, with nothing injected, therfore with `nil` inside it's `detailBuilding` at 3rd call.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two instances of `ReviewViewController`, and you set the detail only on one of them

```
// 1st instance
let controller = ReviewViewController() 
controller.detailBuilding = detailBuilding
controller.navigationItem.title = ""
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = ""
backItem.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

// 2nd instance, first is deallocated and never used.
navigationController?.pushViewController(ReviewViewController(), animated: true)
// replace with:
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After this I was also able to remove the call in the viewDidAppear method.